# On click with 2 ids update the .map() array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to update the .map(maped) array on second button click. What i need to Archive is on second button click update the array.

I need to watch for changes then call the `.map()` again.

```js
$("#send, #more_column").click(function(e) {
  if (this.id == 'more_column') {
    console.log("Second button click"); //im inside second button click
    // here i need to update the device_id[] array add one more item to array or more
  }

  device_id = $('input:enabled[name="device_id[]"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val(); // $(this).val()
  }).get();

});
```

How can i update the **device_id** array when second button is clicked.
If the second button is clicked more then once again update the **device_id** array.

Any ideas ?

Comment: That's what your code is doing. If it's not working as you expect, please provide more details about why that is

Comment: Its not updating, I need to get the new added Inputs to the array. eg run the .map again.

Comment: So just call `.map()` on those elements again...?

Comment: I call its the `.map()` inside the second button but it wont detect the new added inputs. I need to watch for changes somehow, but idk how :/

Comment: I save the array when i click on `#send` when i click on `#more_column` i append more items: Basicly i need to watch for changes and update the array on `#more_column` click

Comment: If you need an item added to the array then you need to move the `more_column` if statement *after* the map.  (If I'm understanding your problem, which I don't think I am)

Comment: Man i have 2 buttons, with one i save the array with other i append more inputs if clicked:
If only ``#send` is clicked then just save, if `#more_column` was clicked then i first will append more inputs then here i have to watch for changes and update the array.

Comment: I mean... if you ever heard of `Array.prototype.push()` that should solve what you're asking. Since it seems like an *too easy solution* I still don't get your problem. So yeah `device_id.push("Use google")`

Comment: Man i need to watch for div changes if anything was append to the html then update the array. Do you understand this?

Comment: @Edo Please update your question so people here are able to reproduce the problem. ~ [Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing event handlers doesn't make sense in this scenario.  It's much better to keep the code simple, so have an event handler for the add button and an event handler for the send button, and make the add button also call the send handler...

```
function send() {
    device_id = $('input:enabled[name="device_id[]"]').map(function() {
        return $(this).val(); // $(this).val()
    }).get();
}

function add() {
    // add whatever you need to add here
    // execute the "send" handler...
    send();
}

$("#send").on("click", send);
$("#more_column").on("click", add);
```